# Changing UITableViewCell when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app I have a UITableView and I have two different custom UITableViewCells.  The UITableView is initially loaded with one kind of custom UITableViewCell.  When one of the cells is selected in my UITableView I would like to change the cell that was selected with the other type of custom UITableViewCell.  Is this possible?  Let me hear what you got.

Thanks,
NSNolan

```
#pragma mark - UITableView delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.array count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if(indexPath.row == [self currentCellIndex]) {
        [self setCurrentCellIndex:-1];

        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        OldCell *cell = (OldCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        [self setCurrentCellIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        NewCell *cell = (NewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }        
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"OldCell";

    OldCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OldCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is there particular block of code that is giving you trouble? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking or the relevance of the link.

Comment: You can achieve this by having a instance variable which holds the current selected indexPath. Then reload the tableview. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can check if the indexPath equals to selectedIndexPath and then initialize the second custom cell.

Comment: This is what I was trying to due exactly but I wasn't able to load the new nib into the old cell.  Do you have any code example for this that you could post?

Comment: @NSNolan The relevance of the link is the table view progrmaming guide. This is a very open ended question as is. You should what you have tried, and point out a sepcific problem you are havning, along with relevant code. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `didSelectRow...` method, you need to update a flag (stored in an instance variable) indicating the new "mode" of the cell. Then reload the row by calling `tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing in the selected indexPath.

In your `cellForRow...` method, use the flag to determine which of the two types of cells to use for the row.